# iPhone (Safari and Chrome both) position: fixed bug?

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I have this website

On desktop everything works fine, but on iPhone (Safari and Chrome both) I have problem with preloader:

[Bug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf8oH.png)

CSS:

```
    .preloader_wrapper {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: #000;
        z-index: 100500;
    }
    .preloader {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .preloader::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 4px solid #951b25;
        border-left-color: transparent;
        border-right-color: transparent;
        animation: spin 1s linear infinite; 
    }
    @keyframes spin {
        0% {
            transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
        }
        50% {
            transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.2);
        }
        100% {
            transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="preloader_wrapper">
        <div class="preloader"></div>
    </div>
```

Due to my googling I think the problem is in position fixed. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I think .preloader absolute positing might fix it. I'm on a phone right now so can't test it. Otherwise I suggest to try display; flex; with justify and alignment props on the .preloader_wrapper and remove all the positioning stuff from the .preloader itself.

Comment: Thanks, flex fixed this issue. But I'm really interested why .preloader relative positioning doesn't work on iPhone..

Comment: That's because the keyframe was resetting the transform xy values. It should work if you add the transform props to these as well.